# text inside an image clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert

i have an image with a text and i want that this text inside the image can be clickable, but i have a problem : the image appears inside an alert box (i have used sweet alert). When i click a button appears me an alert box with these image and after i see the image i want to click the text inside it, how i can do that ?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="Alert()">Button</a> 

    <script>
      function Alert() {
        swal({
          title: "Sweet!",
          text: "Here's a custom image.",
          imageUrl: "images/image.jpg"
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want the text clickable like a link?

Comment: yes exactly.. these image have a text i want when user put the mouse over the image can click on the text like a link

Answer (score 1):

[*SweetAlert2*](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) just creates a DOM Element. If you inspect it with your developer tools you'll quickly find out that the `text` is wrapped in an element which you can get with `swal.getContent()`.

You could easily hook a click listener on this element. For simplicity i assume you use jQuery:

```
<script>
  function Alert() {
    swal({
      title: "Sweet!",
      text: "<i>Here's a custom image.</i>",
      imageUrl: "images/image.jpg",
      html: true
    });

    $(swal.getContent()).on('click', function(ev) {
         console.log('Do something when the text is clicked');
    });

    $(swal.getImage()).on('click', function(ev) {
         console.log('Do something when the image is clicked');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Hope i could help.

---

Update: Thanks [limonite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331425/limonte) for the Edit (you don't need to look for the selector, `swal.getContent()` will provide you directly with the element you're looking for).

Also i added the `html` property as example as seen in other answers, if you would prefer something like a "real" link you could just use an `<a>` tag.

Comment: assuming that my image have a text for example : click here. Image an image with the text : click here;  now i want that when user see the image he can put their mouse up the text and click on it but the text is inside the image not external

Comment: added the alternative, thanks again limonte. You can add the listener on the image directly. If you want to work only if the text inside your image is clicked...this...would be weird. Maybe doable if you know the exact measures. you could probably find out where inside the image the user clicked and calculate if he hitted the text. but this won't work dynamically for every image you put in there..its just an image.

Comment: how i can make the white text clickable

Comment: This is soooo bad practice, i can't really answer that with a good conscience ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `html : true` option and put the markup in the `text` option value:

```
swal({
  title: "Sweet!",
  text: "<a href="/your/url">A custom image<a>",
  html: true
});
```

so says the documentation: https://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use `html: true` to allow html to be used in the text of alert box.

```
swal({
  title: "Sweet!",
  text: "<a href='some_url'>Here's a custom image<a>",
  imageUrl: "images/image.jpg",
  html: true
});
```

Here's the link http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

You can scroll down to the HTML Message part to check it.

Answer (score -1):

Sweet Alert supports HTML in text. So you can easily do something like this:

```
<script>
  function Alert() {
    swal({
      title: "Sweet!",
      text: "<a href='www.somelink.com'>Some Clickable Link</a>",
      imageUrl: "images/image.jpg",
      html :true
    });
  }
</script>
```

I got this information from the sweet alert site!
http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Cheers!

Comment: You are bringing the confusion by not making any difference between SweetAlert and SweetAlert2

Comment: Whoops, I didn't mean to grab someone else's html. I have updated my answer to reflect accordingly.